# If EntityB inherits from EntityA, must I also make a CDEntityB class that inherits from CDEntityA?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I mean... is that a good idea?

Comment: How does CDEntityA relate to EntityA and CDEntityB relate to EntityB ?

Comment: However you can imagine. It's a very general question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Classes and entities are two completely different things.  They do not need to mirror each other and in many cases it is a very bad idea.

Entity to class mapping is also not one-to-one so you can have one class that is being used by multiple entities if you so choose.